# Rowstyle – Polyglossia Latin clash: illegal pream-token

Tags: tables, formatting, polyglossia, updating

After updating my TeXLive today (last updated about six weeks ago), the following MWE will stop with the recrimination:

```
Illegal pream-token (^): `c' used.
```

If I comment the Latin activation line, then no problem. I have tried all variants of Latin, and checked the manuals of `array` and `polyglossia` for hints, but I can't spot the culprit, any ideas? Any recommended hack?

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}

    \setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}} % row format
    \newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
    \newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
      #1\ignorespaces
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{$c^c^c}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}   1&2&3\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `latin`, the character `^` is a shorthand, so it is different in the preamble than in the body of the document. Shorthands used to be activated as soon as the language is loaded, not any longer.

You have three strategies:

1. transfer `\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}` after `\begin{document}`
2. use the cryptic code

   ```
   \begingroup\lccode`~=`^\lowercase{\endgroup
     \newcolumntype{~}{>{\currentrowstyle}}%
   }
   ```
3. use a different character for the column type

My preference would go to the last option.

Fourth strategy: forget about `\rowstyle`.

Comment: Forget about \rowstyle? You mean to apply it for every cell of the row, typically the header. I don't know, it is quite cool to have a key 'header format', for instance, make it \bfseries and have it applied to the whole header. True, if you have a \multicolumn, you have to do it by hand anyway. Well, you are right, it is cool but not as useful as it might seem

Comment: @RaoulKessels It can be useful if you need to alternate styles between rows (but that usually makes for bad tables). For a single row it adds an unneeded complication, IMHO. Pasting a few `\bfseries` commands is not so difficult and time consuming.

Comment: I agree on both points. The only thing is that it makes the row very long in the source. Usually you get a header in two lines while the main body is nicely aligned. Then, when using \rowstyle, you need to put something between the the alignment specifications. I use |, which then makes it difficult to place vertical lines in the table, which are, I am very sure you will agree, horrible ;-)

Comment: I went with your option 3, and changed the character to ª. So using `\newcolumntype{ª}{>{\currentrowstyle}}` everything runs nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

gloss-latin makes the `^` active at begin document. This means the tabular doesn't recognize it as a defined columntype anymore. If you activate the shorthand it works again:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}

    \setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}} % row format

    \newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
      #1\ignorespaces
    }

\shorthandon{^} %<---
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{$c^c^c}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}   1&2&3\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This makes the MWE run fine, but with my full preamble, loading many other packages, it became complicated... so I went with @egreg 's suggestion and used a different character; see my comment to his answer.